# Memory reference traces with Intel Pin of packet processing applications

Tags: instrumentation, intel-pin, packet-injection

I'm learning how to use Intel Pin and I have a couple of questions regarding the instrumentation process for a particular usecase. I would like to create a memory reference trace of a simple packet processing application. I have developed the required pintool for that purpose and my questions are the following.

- Assuming I use the same network packet trace at all times as input to my packet processing application and let's say I instrument that same application on two different machines. How will the memory reference traces be different? Apparently Pin instruments userspace and is architecture independent so I wouldn't expect to see big qualitative differences in the two output memory reference traces. Is that assumption correct ?
- How will the memory trace change if I experiment with the rate at which I inject network packets to my packet processing application ? Or will it change at all and if yes how can I detect how the output traces differ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are  doing something related to following the data flow / code flow of the network packet, probably closely related to data tainting?

> Assuming I use the same network packet trace at all times as input to my packet processing application and let's say I instrument that same application on two different machines. How will the memory reference traces be different?

There are multiple factors that can make the memory trace trace quite different, the crucial point being "two different machines":

- Exact copy of the same O.S : traces nearly the same (as the stack, heap and virtual memory manager will work the same) except addresses will change (ASLR).
- Same O.S (but not necessarily the same version of the system shared libraries): probably the same as above if there is no recompilation of the target application. Maybe minor difference due to the heap manager that can behave differently.
- Different O.S (where a recompilation of the traced application is needed): completely different traces.

> Apparently Pin instruments userspace and is architecture independent so I wouldn't expect to see big qualitative differences in the two output memory reference traces. Is that assumption correct ?

Pintools needs to be recompiled for different archs, but the pintool itself should not change the way the target application is traced (same pintool + same os + same application = nearly same trace).

> How will the memory trace change if I experiment with the rate at which I inject network packets to my packet processing application ?

This is system dependent and also depends on your insertion point(s). If you start tracing at `recv()` or `recvfrom()` there might be some congestion or dropped packets (UDP) if, for example, the rate is too important. Depends on the protocol, your receive window, etc. There are really multiple factors here.

> Or will it change at all and if yes how can I detect how the output traces differ ?

I'd probably check the code flow rather than the data flow for this case (seems easier to me). Given exactly the same packet but different rates, if the code branches are not the same (maybe at the basic block (BBL) level), this immediately tells that the same packet is handled differently.